# How to enable "persistent mode" in Windows failover cluster manager 2012?

Tags: windows, cluster-computing, failover

In Windows Server 2008 R2 there was a checkbox named "Enable persistent mode" on a General tab in the Properties of a cluster resource.

In Windows Server 2012 that seems to have disappeared.

My cluster resource is a "generic script" resource (not that it makes any difference).

How do I enable "persistent mode" for a cluster resource in Windows Server 2012?

Thanks

Comment: The "What's New in Failover Clustering in Windows Server 2012" document can be found at https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/dn265972.aspx#BKMK_DEP. I read it but didn't see any mention of what I'm looking for.

Comment: SO is not the right place for your question. You should ask over at serverfault.

Comment: You're right, thanks, I did just now.

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation it seems to me that 2012 either defaults to or is hard-coded to "persistent mode" and they've disabled changing the value with the GUI.